# How to restrict emails' css so that it won't affect the app's style?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, email, html-email

I'm trying to build an email client in Angular. The problem I encounter is sometimes the message includes `style`, hence it may affect the app's css (e.g. anchors become purple when opening that message). Otherwise, if I remove this tag, the format wouldn't be shown as expected. Do you have any suggestions or documents in regard of this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using iframes. Not the best-practice solution but it'd work.

Comment: Do you mean iframe? I receive messages from REST so there's no point to include a hyperlink.

Comment: Do _what_ using "frames" which is ...?

Comment: He might mean using `iframes`. Have each email render in an `iframe` within the webmail app so that the email code doesn't impact the webmail client. This is how some webmail's do it.